# package compilation error in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY jobs_package as

PROCEDURE add_job (

        p_job_id  NUMBER,
        p_job_title  VARCHAR2,
        p_min_salary NUMBER,
        p_max_salary NUMBER) AS

BEGIN


       UPDATE jobs
       SET job_title = p_job_title,
               min_salary = p_min_salary,
               max_salary = p_MAX_salary; -- error appears here underlined
       WHERE 
               job_id = p_job_id;

EXCEPTION
       WHEN DATA_NOT_FOUND THEN

               Raise_application_error(-204940, 'This Job cannot be found. ' || p_job_title 
               || ' Job ID: ' || p_job_id);

END add_job;

END jobs_package;
/
show err
```

Answer (score 1):

take out the semi-colon

```
max_salary = p_MAX_salary;

UPDATE jobs
       SET job_title = p_job_title,
               min_salary = p_min_salary,
               max_salary = p_MAX_salary
       WHERE 
               job_id = p_job_id;
```

Comment: happens to everyone :)